# How to use same variable across various controllers - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.3

I am using ruby 2.3.1 and rails 3.2.1. I need to initialize a variable called `has_sub_menu = false` in application controller.

In my application i am using more than 30 controllers and only two controllers contains sub-menu, so i need to assign `has_sub_menu = true` to these controllers to validate it in layout file.

This is my `application.rb`

```
has_sub_menu = false
```

some_controller01.rb

```
has_sub_menu = true
```

some_controller02.rb

```
has_sub_menu = true
```

I tried like this in `layout.rb`,

```
if controller.has_sub_menu == true
  show_menu_items
end
```

`show_menu_items` will be available in that two controller and currently i am not able to access the `has_sub_menu` value in layout file

I know in c# I can declare the variable as static and access it in any file using object.

Like wise how can i declare a variable in `application` controller and assign different value to that variable in other two controller and I need to access that value in layout.rb file for sub-menu validation.

Comment: shouldnt that go in the application_controller  as a method instead of application.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an instance method in `application_controller.rb` and override it in any controller, that should have different value:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def has_sub_menu # unless overriden in descending controller, value will be true
    true
  end
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController
  def has_sub_menu
     false
  end
end
```

This way you have access to `has_sub_menu` "method" in all controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can create a helper method and check for controller name

```
module ApplicationHelper
  CONTROLLERS_LIST = ['UsersController']

  def has_sub_menu
    CONTROLLERS_LIST.exclude?(params[:controller])
  end
end
```

Comment: not that straightforward and clear for those, who see controller's code for the first time, but indeed a good option!

Comment: He says he need to check it in `layout` so it's  better to add this logic in helper method

Comment: I am looking for a solution to validate it  instead of controller_name.

Comment: In that case go for the solution @andrey has posted